# PHP calendar with left write navigation

Tags: php, calendar

I'm trying to create a calendar with only PHP.
Here is what I have done:

```
<?pop
            $date = time():

            $day = date("d", $date);
            $month = date("m", $date);
            $year = date("y", $date);


            $firstDay = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);

            $title = date("F", $firstDay);
            $dayOfWeek = date("D", $firstDay);

            switch($dayOfWeek) {
                case "Sun": $blank = 0; break;
                case "Mon": $blank = 1; break;
                case "Tue": $blank = 2; break;
                case "Wed": $blank = 3; break;
                case "Thu": $blank = 4; break;
                case "Fri": $blank = 5; break;
                case "Sat": $blank = 6; break;
            }

            $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);

            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr><th>" . $title . " " . $year "</th></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thu</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td></tr>";

            $dayCount = 1;
            while ($blank > 0) {
                echo "<td></td>";
                $blank--;
                $dayCount++;
            }

            $dayNum = 1;
            while ($dayNum <= $daysInMonth) {
                echo "<td>" . $dayNum . "</td>";
                $dayNum++;
                $dayCount++;

                if ($dayCount > 7) {
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                    $dayCount = 1;
                }
            }

            while ($dayCount > 1 and $dayCount <= 7) {
                echo "<td></td>";
                $dayCount++;
            }

            echo "</tr></table>";

            ?>
```

The logic seems to be fine (at leaset to me for now). However, when I tried this on my server, I got this error message:

`"; echo "" . $title . " " . $year ""; echo "SunMonTueWedThuFriSat"; $dayCount = 1; while ($blank > 0) { echo ""; $blank--; $dayCount==; } $dayNum = 1; while ($dayNum <= $daysInMonth) { echo "" . $dayNum . ""; $dayNum++; $dayCount++; if ($dayCount > 7) { echo ""; $dayCount = 1; } } while ($dayCount > 1 and $dayCount <= 7) { echo ""; $dayCount++; } echo ""; ?>`

I have absolutely no idea why this happened. I would like to ask for you help on this.
Also, I wonder if I can add two arrow so the user can click on them in order to go to the next or previous months using only PHP.

Thanks

Comment: that's not an error message. that's your raw php code being rendered as if it was html, exactly as @Amit has said below: your opening PHP tag is wrong, so the PHP interpreter never fires up and nothing ever gets executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Check what you've written in the PHP opening tag at the begining of the file... It has to be 
`<?php` not `<?pop`

Do Refer this [PHP Basic Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) which explains the basic PHP syntax

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise that mistake I made. I did it. It turn out to be a calendar as I expected but I'm still working on how to make the arrows.